# Data is not displayed in the table

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have created a small application,in which i have draged and droped a NSTableView onto the window and binded to an datasource, in the datasource i have created NSMutableArray and added 2 records to it. And also defined methods numberOfRowsInTableView and rest of the methods.
When i run the application it is showing the rows but the data is not displaying.

Comment: (best Buffalo Bill impersonation) "It puts the data in the taaaable."

Answer (score 1):

So. You've connected your table view's `datasource` outlet to some controller object that adopts `NSTableDataSource` protocol.

You mention `numberOfRowsInTableView`, which tells the table how many rows it should expect but lump together the "rest of the methods." One of those other methods is exactly responsible for showing the *data* for a given row and column.

What seems to be happening is this:

> Table: *"How many rows we got here?"*
>
> Data Source: *"Three."*
>
> Table: *"Gimme the object to display at
>   row 0, column 0."*
>
> Data Source: *[ sound of crickets
>   chirping ]*

You should probably post the exact code you're using for your implementation of the `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method. Remember to include the method signature itself, given its importance in being recognized as the selector the protocol is looking for.

Comment: - (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(int)row{
 NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
 
 FoodItem *item = [items objectAtIndex:row];
 return [item valueForKey:identifier];
}

Comment: 2011-05-14 17:07:18.450 TableMenu[31334:a0f] *** Illegal NSTableView data source (<MyDataSource: 0x10052ccc0>).  Must implement numberOfRowsInTableView: and tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:

Comment: It is showing the 2 blanks rows indicating that there are rows but data is not visible

Comment: In the future, please edit your question and post your code there, properly formatted so we can read it. It makes it easier for others to help.

Comment: Your method signature is wrong. Try copying and pasting it from the API reference.

Comment: Please mark helpful answers as "accepted" to encourage others to help you in the future. :-)